# Nginx shows wrong time/timezone

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

How to fix `Nginx` timezone? I've configured `nginx` to serve a directory but datetime of creation is one hour after my real time.

I've added to `/etc/init.d/nginx`

```
export TZ='Europe/Bratislava'
```

then

```
sudo service nginx reload
sudo service nginx restart
```

But it didn't help, there should be 14:19 instead of 13:19.

**EDIT**

Tried to change **Ubuntu** default timezone but the datetimes aren't changed.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default, nginx outputs the directory index in UTC time. If you want it to display the time in your local timezone, you should set the [autoindex_localtime](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html#autoindex_localtime) directive to on.

```
autoindex_localtime on
```

Comment: Note that it's not necessarily to be on `location` level, one could put it directly in `server` block on top.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, you need to set your system timezone. You can use `timedatectl list-timezones` to get the names.

```
sudo timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Moscow
```

Secondly, set [autoindex_localtime](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html#autoindex_localtime) directive `autoindex_localtime on;` in nginx config file for your site, for example `/etc/nginx/sites-avaliable/default`. Put the directive before `autoindex on;`

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/dir;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        autoindex_localtime on;
        autoindex on;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the timezone you can run the following command in your instance:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

and then choose your preferred timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Also the problem can be from `php.ini`. If you use php, change the time zone in `[Date]`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

look for /etc/init.d/ folder and open "nginx" file

$ sudo nano /etc/init.d/nginx
and add TZ value for timezone

e.g export TZ = "Asia/Singapore"

Answer (score -1):

check timezone of your system if require then set your own time zone then reboot . after reboot you will see correct time